# printing from android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and I am trying to send a print to a wireless printer(Epson Wireless printer) which is not connected to any computer but able to receive data from android application. Android O.S. is installed on this printer. But I am not able to connect with this printer. I have one document file of EPSON in which all the classes and methods are given for printing.

Comment: It would be better if you at least say the model of the printer.

Comment: I am designing it for Epson E220d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Epson official SDK available for Android devices,

[Epson SDKs for iOS, Android and Windows 8 POS Applications](http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/)

The SDK also contains two sample application source codes which describes everything needed to print a sample document.

There's also a test application available in the Play Store to give you a basic overview of the SDK's feature,

[Epson TM Utility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epson.tmutility&hl%20en)

Comment: You are most welcome! Please make the answer accepted if that was helpful.